# set gravity on each object Gazebo7

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am tryng to set the gravity on each individual objects in gazebo. I am spawning a robot model that needs to have 0 gravity. But The objects it needs to interact with need to have gravity,so they don't float away. I am not sure how to accomplish this I can turn on/off gravity for the entire world, but not individual models. Here is my world file,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <sdf version="1.4">
    <world name="default">
      
      <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
      </include>


      <include>


        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
      </include>
      
         <include>
        <pose>0 10 0 0 0 0</pose>
         <gravity>0 0 -9.81</gravity>
        <uri>model://button_panel</uri>
        
      </include>

      <gravity>0 0 0</gravity>
      
    </world>
  </sdf>
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14535/set-gravity-on-each-object-gazebo7/) by [nagoldfarb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2850/nagoldfarb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-10-02**:
lol i see u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

One should probably switch from disabling gravity, to making the robot static. It's still a temporary solution, but static is meant to be at the robot level, not world level. Having different gravity on different objects is a pretty bizarre request.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1